Cone vs. small circle parallel transport
I'm having trouble reconcile the following two seemingly contradicting conclusions (in 2d space):
A cone is flat, because you can unfold it and it's a flat 2d surface.
A cone as shown in the picture below where its surface is tangent to the sphere along a small circle. A vector parallel transported along a small circle will not come back to the same direction, thus the cone surface is curved.

Obviously there's a flaw in my logic somewhere...

This is in a way a Riemann-geometric analogue of the Aharonov--Bohm effect in quantum mechanics.
Consider a manifold $M$ equipped with a linear connection $\nabla$. It is well-known that the parallel transport of the connection $\nabla$ is integrable if and only if the curvature tensor $R$ of the connection vanishes. But what does this actually mean?
It means that given any point $p\in M$, there is an open neighborhood $U\subseteq M$ of $p$ such that given any pair of points $p^\prime,p^{\prime\prime}$ in $U$ and any pair of (piecewise differentiable) curves connecting these two points that run entirely in $U$, parallel transport will be the same along these two curves.
This does not mean that parallel transport is integrable in the entirety of $M$.
In greater details, fix a point $p\in M$, and choose an arbitrary frame $e=(e_1,\dots,e_m)$ at $p$, choose a loop $\gamma$ based at $p$, and parallel transport the entire frame along the loop to get a new frame $e^\prime=(e^\prime_1,\dots,e^\prime_m)$ at $p$. Then there is a unique invertible matrix $A\in\mathrm{GL}(m,\mathbb R)$ such that $e^\prime=eA$ (meaning that $e^\prime_j=A^i_{\ j}e_i$). The set of all matrices $A$ that can be obtained this way form a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(m,\mathbb R)$ called the holonomy group of the connection $\nabla$ at $p$, denoted $\mathrm{Hol}_p(\nabla)$.
It turns out that this group doesn't depend on the point $p$ up to isomorphism (I think we need to assume $M$ to be connected, so let's do that), so in the abstract, we can write $\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)$ instead of $p$. Basically what happens is that for a pair of points $p,q$, there is a (non-unique) invertible matrix $U$ such that $\mathrm{Hol}_q(\nabla)=U\mathrm{Hol}_p(\nabla)U^{-1}$, so these various holonomy groups are related to each other by conjugation and are thus isomorphic, but not canonically so.
Moreover, $\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)$ is a Lie group. Let $\mathrm{Hol}^0(\nabla)$ denote the connected component of the holonomy group containing the identity.
What can be shown is that the subgroup $\mathrm{Hol}^0(\nabla)$ corresponds to parallel transport along contractible loops, so in particular for a simply connected $M$, we have $\mathrm{Hol}^0(\nabla)=\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)$, and elements of the quotient group $\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)/\mathrm{Hol}^0(\nabla)$ depend only on the homotopy class $[\gamma]$ of the loop $\gamma$ we are transporting around.
Furthermore, $\mathrm{Hol}^0(\nabla)=\{1\}$ if and only if $R=0$ (the curvature tensor vanishes).
What this tells us is that for a flat connection $\nabla$, every element of $\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)$ only depends on the homotopy class of the loop we are transporting around, but it is not true in general that $\mathrm{Hol}(\nabla)$ is the trivial group.
Translating this into the example of the cone, the cone can be equipped with a flat metric, (so the corresponding LC connection is flat as well), but it is singular at the origin, so $\pi_1(\mathrm{Cone})\cong\mathbb Z$, and the homotopy classes of loops are characterized by winding number, and parallel transport around a closed loop picks up nontrivial contributions based on winding number.
From a more heuristical point of view, the cone is flat "almost everywhere", except at the origin, where the curvature is infinite (think about it like a Dirac delta singularity). This infinitely concentrated curvature can then cause parallel transport around loops winding around it to be nontrivial.

Racsko. Doesnt answer the question at all.

The path the vector you are describing takes on the cone is a closed circle while the cone is rolled, but it is no longer a closed circle once the cone is sliced and flattened!

This is the only meaninful response to the question
